# how to create a thumbnail of uploaded video file in php without ffmpeg?

Tags: php, thumbnails

Is there any possiblity to create a thumbnail of uploaded video file in php without using ffmpeg.

Comment: i.e. Zencoder http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10240972/create-thumbnail-image-from-video-in-server-in-php

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21179522/472495) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11383179/472495) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6081045/472495) or maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3147428/472495), found using [this search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+thumbnail+video+without+ffmpeg).

Comment: I also recently added comments [to this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23657717/472495) recently. In essence, try ImageMagick on the command line - it is installed in most shared hosting situations.

Comment: cant find a reason why this question is voted up :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most server side scripts rely on ffmpeg, so if you can't use that you can either upload the video to an external service but that would mean sending the whole file OR you could try creating them client-side in the browser -- [Generate thumbnails from video files using HTML5's video tag and canvas](https://gist.github.com/adamjimenez/5917897)

If however you can't use ffmpeg for installtion reasons you could [look at a wrapper](https://code.google.com/p/phpvideotoolkit/) -- It currently provides FFmpeg-PHP emulation in pure PHP so you wouldn't need to compile and install the module.

Comment: Um - actually the wrapper does require ffmpeg - and the link you posted is already outdated. https://github.com/buggedcom/phpvideotoolkit-v2

Answer (score 2):

In the past I have used [this website](https://transloadit.com/) to do video conversion and create thumbnails. It works very well and have both free and paid plans.

The system consists of several "robots" that do different jobs. These robots can read your videos if you put them in a public folder with an URI or Amazon S3 for example. The actions that the robot must do are defined in "templates" in JSON and have a PHP SDK. Have a look at the [docs](https://transloadit.com/docs).

P.S: I'm not related with transloadit, seems like I am a commercial guy...